# How to get sold product quantity in orderplaced observer , Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How to get sold product quantity in Orderplaced observer , Magento 2 ?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail exactly what & where u need sold product detial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create custom module add **events.xml** file at

**app/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="mycustom_controller_success_action" instance="Vendor\Modulename\Observer\AfterPlaceOrder"  />
    </event>
</config>
```

Add observer at **app/code/Vendor/Modulename/Observer/AfterPlaceOrder.php**
add below code to it

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class AfterPlaceOrder implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $order = $this->order->load($orderId);
        $itemCollection = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach($itemCollection as $item){
            $item->getQtyOrdered(); //item ordered qty
        }
    }

}
```